# How to show alertDialog in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine for my game. In that I want to give option to user when they click on an image, one alert dialog should pop up. my code is below.
here is the method

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyGame.this.getApplicationContext());
        builder.setMessage("Hello");
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        return alert;
    default:
        return null;
    }       
}
```

and I am calling this method by this statement :

```
{
onCreateDialog(1).show();
```

}

And i am getting this error message :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(672): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateDialog(1).show();` is wrong.
Call `showDialog(1);` instead.

And also change your Builder like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyGame.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use onCreateDialog(1).show();

Use

```
showDialog(1)
```

instead

and also replace MyGame.this.getApplicationContext() with MyGame.this

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean message = false;

use in the method which u r using...

if (!message ) { 

            if (user.equals("") || user.equals(null)) {
                ErrorText = "hello";

                username.requestFocus();
                isError = true;


if (message ) {
            alertbox.setMessage(ErrorText);
            alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        }
                    });
            alertbox.show();
            isError = false;
        }
```